# How do I retrieve the xpath of a clicked element in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-ide

Is there a way for me to select an element in a web browser, using Selenium IDE and get an XPath of the item I clicked on (regardless of whether it is text or button?)

TIA

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "the" XPath.  Every element has many Xpath, there is no definitive.

Some Xpath are brittle, some are stable, some are reliable, some are unstable.

The "best" and most suitable has to be a human decision. Browsers allow you to test and experiment with Xpath.

Comment: Sorry I meant any XPath.

Answer (score 1):

You can get "the" xpath - but it would be an absolute path to the element which is usually not reliable and very fragile. In the [`firebug`](https://getfirebug.com/) firefox extension find an element and select "Copy xpath" from the menu.

Comment: I'm aware that there are other firefox extensions, but I'm looking into a way for me to use Selenium IDE to find an xpath from just a click of a mouse while recording.

Comment: @Edasaur ok, I see your point. Sorry for the confusion. My point though is that both firebug and selenium IDE are must have for browser interface testing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium IDE, click the `Select` button beside the `Target` text box. And then move your mouse pointer to the web element that you want to check (it will be highlighted). Click on the element. In the IDE, click the `Target` dropdown box. Select the `xpath` that you want to use.

Alternatively, if you do not want to use IDE, you can also use the `Developer Tool` panel in Chrome or `Firebug` plugin in Firefox to get the xpath.

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium IDE, by keeping the recording mode on, then clicking on the element you want to capture, you can find all the locators of that web element that are captured by the Selenium IDE (if the selenium IDE is able to capture the web element). After recording that element in IDE , click on the drop down in the **Target** bar (on right end of **Target** bar), you will find all the locators including **xPath** (css as well).